# Как узнать нажатую клавишу?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать в Javascript нажали какую клавишу?

Comment: Google ` События `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/keyboard-events

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**event.keyCode**

`event.keyCode` возвращает ASCII-код клавиши, но он считается устаревшим. ([KeyboardEvent.code - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode))

**event.code**

Также есть свойство `event.code`, которое возвращает строковое представление клавиши. ([KeyboardEvent.code - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code))

```js
window.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  console.log('keyCode: ', event.keyCode)
  console.log('code: ', event.code)
  console.log('------------------')
})
```

```html
<div>press any key</div>
```

Comment: Я бы добавил ещё информацию о эвентах для отслеживания